# "Double or Nothing" gambling machine code can't reach past 15 combo

Tags: c++

So I wrote a code to simulate a gambling machine from a game. Basically, you press a button, and you have a chance to double your the credits you earn. On the other hand, if you this fails, you have to start over. An example run might be:

```
Start of run 1:
0
1
2
Start of run 2:
0
1
Start of run 3:
0
Start of run 4:
0
1
2
```

It works fine. I have the code do a certain amount of runs (determined by user input into 'n') and outputs the maximum combo that was reached in all of those runs. It also tells when the highest combo was surpassed.

The problem is that after a certain amount of runs, the highest combo cannot surpass 15 for whatever reason. Literally every time I input 10 million or more (, it gives 15. It just doesn't seem right given the fact that it doesn't match the probability at all.

Is there something wrong with the way I seeded it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n = 1;

    srand(time(0));
    while (n > 0) {
        cin >> n;

        int highestCombo = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int combo = 0;
            while (true) {
                int r = (rand() % 2) + 1;

                if (r == 1) {
                    combo++;
                }
                else if (r == 2) {
                    if (combo > highestCombo) {
                        highestCombo = combo;
                        cout << combo << " at #" << i << endl;
                    }
                    combo = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Highest Combo: " << highestCombo << endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT: So it seems that it might just be my IDE. Weird. I'm using Dev-C++ since I just wanted to quickly write it. However, cpp.sh goes above 15 and into the 20s.

Comment: Please add the relevant lines of code to you **question**.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: So basically what you're trying to do is wait for `rand()` to return an odd number more than 15 times in a row...?

Comment: ... thats a probability of 1/ (2^15), maybe you just didnt try it often enough

Comment: Yes. I'm seeing the maximum amount that a rand() will return an odd number in a row. I realize now that this problem has only occurred when using Dev-C++. When using any other IDE it's just fine, and it goes way above 15. I don't particularly like Dev-C++ so I guess it's not much of a problem, but I really don't know why it's doing this.

I've also done it way too many times. 2^15 is 32768. Hypothetically, it would EASILY be done in 10 million runs, right? Plus it's going well above 15 in other IDEs. Just a strange problem with Dev-C++ I think. Or maybe just a different setting within it.

Comment: I can confirm that using your code in visual studio 2010 I encounter the same problem

Comment: please note that `rand()` is broken, especially when used as `(rand() % x) + y;`. It might well be that you never get more than 15 odd numbers in a row. If you want real pseudo randomness you should use the facilities from `<random>`

Comment: ...also iirc the lower bits of `rand()` are less random than the higher ones. You can try to shift the return by some bits before doing the modulo. Still not as good as using `<random>` but maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer seams to come from tobi303. I tested his solution for you and using "< random >" instead works much better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int n = 1;

//srand(time(NULL));

std::mt19937 rng;
rng.seed(std::random_device()());
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> rand(1,2); 
while (n > 0) {
    cin >> n;

    int highestCombo = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int combo = 0;
        while (true) {
            //int r = (rand() % 2);
            int r = rand(rng);

            if (r == 1) {
                combo++;
            }
            else if (r == 2) {
                if (combo > highestCombo) {
                    highestCombo = combo;
                    cout << combo << " at #" << i << endl;
                }
                combo = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i == n - 1)
        {
            cout << " i " << i << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Highest Combo: " << highestCombo << endl;
}
```

}